# Pivot_longer: names_sep does not work with dot (".") indicator where to split

Tags: r, tidyr

While using tidyr's pivot_longer I'm trying to split some column names into 2. Using names_sep.

Confusingly to me, it does not work by indicating a dot (".") as the splitting point. If I change the dot (".") to an underscore ("_") (obviously also changing the column names in the example to that) or using a numerical splitting position indicator (here: 4), it works just fine.

However, in the vignette (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) they use a dot as well, and there it seems to work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example data set:

Does not work:

```
test_df <- tibble(
  Zeit_Mod = 1:4,
  DC1.U = c(1, 1,0, 0),
  DC1.I = c(0, 1, 1, 1),
  DC1.P = rnorm(4),
  DC2.U = rnorm(4),
  DC2.I = rep(3, 4),
  DC2.P = rep(-2, 4),
)

test_df_pivoted <- test_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("DC"),
               names_to = c("String", "Variable"),
               values_to = "Measurement",
               names_sep = "."
  )
```

Does work just fine:

```
test_df <- tibble(
  Zeit_Mod = 1:4,
  DC1_U = c(1, 1,0, 0),
  DC1_I = c(0, 1, 1, 1),
  DC1_P = rnorm(4),
  DC2_U = rnorm(4),
  DC2_I = rep(3, 4),
  DC2_P = rep(-2, 4),
)

test_df_pivoted <- test_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("DC"),
               names_to = c("String", "Variable"),
               values_to = "Measurement",
               names_sep = "_"
  )
```

Comment: You need to escape: `names_sep = "\\."`

Comment: You need to escape the `.` as: `names_sep = "\\."` - I'm not sure why the vignette has it wrong - possibly legacy code?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen:  the vignette doesn't use `names_sep = "."` with `pivot_longer()`, it uses it with `pivot_wider()`.  In `pivot_longer()` it is a pattern to match, in `pivot_wider()` it is a character string to insert.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah... I foolishly accepted the premise of the question without checking. More fool me!